# Java Generics, how to do this without instanceof or casting?

Tags: java, oop, generics, polymorphism

```
class Animal {}

class Fish extends Animal {
    void swim() {
        // fish specific logic/side effect
    }
}

class Bird extends Animal {
    void fly() {
        // bird specific logic/side effect
    }
}

interface SideEffect < T extends Animal > {
    void mutateSomething(T);
}

class FishSideEffect implements SideEffect < Fish > {

    @Override
    void mutateSomething(Fish fish) {
        fish.swim() // swim has fish specific side effects
    }

}


void someMethod(Animal animal) {

    FishSideEffect fishSideEffect = new FishSideEffect();
    fishSideEffect(animal); // <- this won't work. 

}
```

When a method parameter is a superclass, what is the best way to execute subclass specific logic?

I'd like to avoid

- `instanceof` and/or casting to the specific subclass
- adding anything to Animal/Bird/Fish

Any helpful terminology for me to research would help too, cheers.

Comment: what is `Example`?

Comment: Sorry, I've changed it to `SideEffect`

Comment: If you have a reference to a superclass, then if you want to execute a specific subclass's method you MUST cast to the subclass.  The only time you don't is when the method is abstract in the superclass and implemented in the subclass.  This is a fundamental aspect of the way inheritance works in Java.

Comment: but of course this `fishSideEffect(animal);` will not work. it expects a `Fish` and you pass an `Animal`. At runtime, it might be a `Fish`, but at compile time that does not matter, this will fail.

Comment: @JimGarrison cheers, that helps a lot.  I figured that's how it worked but wanted a second opinion - appreciate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a reference to a superclass, then if you want to execute a specific subclass's method you MUST cast to the subclass. The only time you don't is when the method is abstract in the superclass and implemented in the subclass. This is a fundamental aspect of the way inheritance works in Java.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't what generics were created for.

Generics were created for extended static time type checking... Basically, to warn you not to try to put a `Bar` object in a `Foo` collection.

the best way to design `SideEffect` would be as a (static or non-static) inner class. You could add a static method to Fish like

```
public static void registerSideEffect(SideEffect)
```

to keep track of the side effects that a Fish can have. The other thing you could do is in Animal, add

```
public void applySideEffect(SideEffect<T> effect)
```

where T is your Animal generic type. This could help to limit (at static time) applying to wrong SideEffect to an Animal